# React native version 0.47.1 build failed error: com.facebook.react:react-native:0.47.1 Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0

Tags: react-native, okhttp

I updated react-native to latest version(0.47.1) and then initialized a new react-native project but can not run it at all. There is a SSL problem with okhttp3 that i was not installed it individually. I added the certificate in cacerts file existing in this folder: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security`; but still have problem.

This is the stack trace:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
    > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0.
        Required by:
            Limo:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.47.1
        > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0.
            > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.6.0/okhttp-3.6.0.pom'.
                > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.6.0/okhttp-3.6.0.pom'.
                > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0.
        Required by:
            Limo:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.47.1
        > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0.
            > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.6.0/okhttp-urlconnection-3.6.0.pom'.
                > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.6.0/okhttp-urlconnection-3.6.0.pom'.
                > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    > Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0.
        Required by:
            Limo:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.47.1
        > Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0.
            > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.13.0/okio-1.13.0.pom'.
                > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.13.0/okio-1.13.0.pom'.
                > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0.
        Required by:
            Limo:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.47.1 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.0.1
        > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0.
            > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.6.0/okhttp-3.6.0.pom'.
                > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.6.0/okhttp-3.6.0.pom'.
                > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I am using jre7, Android Studio 1.5 and gradle 1.5.0.
Is there any compatibility issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Silly question! It seems that JVM does not reload cacerts file properly by only restarting adb, although it was including in list of certificates after adb restart. But a system restart is needed to remove the ssl error.